# LDAP connection slow with userPrincipalName login

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

In an application we have recently changed the login from sAMAccountname to UserPrincipaleName. (reason: the 20 character restriction)

Everything works, but is very slow when connecting to the AD/ldap. But if I use the ip address in the DirectoryEntry  path, it is connecting very fast.

Please take a look at this code example. I did test the blocks of code in different orders, to rule out caching. But the result stay’s the same. For failover and load balance I want to use the domain name and not the ip address.

Does someone know what is causing the delay I’m facing?

```
 //login with sAMAccountname + FQDN => 1 second
DirectoryEntry d1 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://abc.local/CN=AdminF,OU=Users,DC=abc,DC=local", "admin.123f", "password");
Console.WriteLine("d1 {0} {1}", d1.Properties["DisplayName"][0], DateTime.Now - sttime);

sttime= DateTime.Now;
//login with userPrincipaleName + ip address => 1 second
DirectoryEntry d2 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://10.xx.xx.1/CN=AdminF,OU=Users,DC=abc,DC=local", "admin.f@abc.local", "password");
Console.WriteLine("d2 {0} {1}", d2.Properties["DisplayName"][0], DateTime.Now - sttime);

sttime= DateTime.Now;
//login with userPricipaleName + FQDN //=> 30-63 seconds!!!!
DirectoryEntry d3 = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://abc.local/CN=AdminF,OU=Users,DC=abc,DC=local", "admin.f@abc.local", "password");
Console.WriteLine("d3 {0} {1}", d3.Properties["DisplayName"][0], DateTime.Now - sttime); 

// user admin.f@abc.local is the same user as admin.123f.
```

Comment: Have you tried the constructor overload that takes a `AuthenticationTypes` enum, especially with the `FastBind` and/or `ServerBind` flags? See documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes.aspx

Comment: Hi Cremor, no I did not try to overload. But your answer did ask me what the difference is between the two logins...and that is the reference to the domain in the username.

Comment: I have found a cause. Our domain contains 4 domain controllers, 2 of them are offside and are behind a firewall. The app can only reach the 2 nearby. Fake the result in the hosts file did not work. It has something to do with the GC.
When I change in the D1 line the name to ABC/admin.123f I have the same slow connection. It has something to do with adding the domain to the account. 
I’m not completely understand it. Why using the ip address is always fast. And when I connect with an incorrect login the error is instantly
But it has nothing to do with sammaccountname vs userprincipalename